# webdriverio get value of waitfor Timeout in runtime

Tags: webdriver-io

I am interested to get the value of the wdio.conf.js property waitforTimeout during execution of the test, how this can be achieved ?

for example :

```
browser.waitUntil(function () {
            var alertText = browser.alertText();
            return alertText && alertText != "";
        }, **3000**, `Alert is expected to be displayed, but actually did not appear`);
```

I want to replace the 3000 with the value currently in waitforTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in `null` instead of a number, it will ignore it and use the default:

```
browser.waitUntil(function () {
    var alertText = browser.alertText();
    return alertText && alertText != "";
}, null, `Alert is expected to be displayed, but actually did not appear`);
```

To answer your original question, you can use the `browser.options` object:
http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/browserobject.html#Get-wdio-config-options